# Multiple join without repeat row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using T-SQL and i've got 3 tables like

Table A

```
id    name
1     abc
2     def
```

Table B

```
rowNo id valueB
1     1  Mat1
2     1  Mat2
3     1  Mat3
4     2  Mat4
5     2  Mat5
```

Table C

```
rowNo id valueC
1     1  val1
2     1  val2
3     2  val3
```

Expected result

```
id    Name    ValueB    ValueC
1     abc     Mat1      Null
1     abc     Mat2      Null
1     abc     Mat3      Null
1     abc     Null      Val1
1     abc     Null      Val2
```

My Query

```
SELECT 
FROM TableA ta
LEFT JOIN TableB tb
ON ta.id=tb.id
LEFT JOIN  TableC tc
ON ta.id = tc.id
WHERE ta.id=1
```

With my query, all valueB and valueC are duplicated. How to get my expected result ?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add the logic which is happening here, as it won't be obvious to most people reading your question.

Comment: your query contains an error, please [edit] your question to correct this.

Comment: @Chris Check my answer and let me know any helps that you need. Best way is to first identify the relationship between the data and put them in the correct code.

Comment: Why do you want `1` for all the resulting `id`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to get you expected result:

```
Select * from (
SELECT ta.id, ta.name, tb.name as ValueB, Null as ValueC
FROM #ta ta
inner JOIN #tb tb
ON ta.id=tb.id
WHERE ta.id=1 

Union

SELECT ta.id, ta.name, Null as ValueB, tc.name as ValueC
FROM #ta ta
inner JOIN  #tc tc
ON ta.id = tc.id
WHERE ta.id=1 
) tmp
```

All code:

```
Drop table if exists #ta
Drop table if exists #tb
Drop table if exists #tc

Create table #ta (
id int not null,
name varchar(3) not null) 

Create table #tb (
id int not null,
name varchar(4) not null)

Create table #tc (
id int not null,
name varchar(4) not null)

insert into #ta Values(1,'abc')
insert into #ta Values(2,'def')

insert into #tb Values(1,'Mat1')
insert into #tb Values(1,'Mat2')
insert into #tb Values(1,'Mat3')
insert into #tb Values(2,'Mat4')

insert into #tc Values(1,'Val1')
insert into #tc Values(1,'Val2')
insert into #tc Values(2,'Val3')

Select * from (
SELECT ta.id, ta.name, tb.name as ValueB, Null as ValueC
FROM #ta ta
inner JOIN #tb tb
ON ta.id=tb.id
WHERE ta.id=1 

Union

SELECT ta.id, ta.name, Null as ValueB, tc.name as ValueC
FROM #ta ta
inner JOIN  #tc tc
ON ta.id = tc.id
WHERE ta.id=1 
) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have the issue that table `A` is being scanned twice.

You can avoid a second scan of table `A` like this:

```sql
SELECT  
     A.id 
    ,A.name
    ,C.valueC 
    ,B.[valueB]
FROM A
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('B'), ('C')) v(tab)
    LEFT JOIN  B 
        ON A.id = B.id AND v.tab = 'B'
    LEFT JOIN C 
        ON A.id = C.id AND v.tab = 'C'
WHERE A.id = 1;
```

Another option, although this may not be as efficient:

```sql
SELECT  
     A.id 
    ,A.name
    ,unioned.valueC 
    ,unioned.[valueB]
FROM A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        NULL as [valueC]
       ,B.[valueB]
      FROM B 
      WHERE A.id = B.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.valueC 
       ,NULL AS valueB 
      FROM C
      WHERE A.id = C.id
) unioned
WHERE A.id = 1;
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution as we can use union to derive your result.

```
SELECT  
     A.id 
    ,A.name
    ,C.valueC 
    ,NULL AS valueB 
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN C 
        ON A.id = C.id 
WHERE A.id = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    A.id 
    ,A.name
    ,NULL as [valueC]
    ,B.[valueB] 
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN  B 
        ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE A.id = 1
```

[image: Output]